# How to implement Touch listener on Multiple button?

Tags: android

i am developing  a word matching game i want to implement a listener. I don't know which which listener I have to use ?

Comment: there are application like word matching , there are multiple alphabets display on screen like A B A L L , when i click on B Then A , L and L respectively the BALL word is valid word it should highlight that word, Now i dont know how to implement a listener on these Buttons

Answer (score 0):

Implement OnTouchListener() on your activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.button1:
                //handle button 1
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                //handle button 1
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                //handle button 1
                break;
            default:
                //default
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use OnClickListener :

```
   Button b1,b2,b3;
    b1= findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b2= findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b3= findViewById(R.id.button3);

    OnClickListener ocl = new OnClickListener (){

       public void onClick(View v){

        switch(v.getId()){

          case R.id.button1:
           // do something
             break;
          case R.id.button2:
          // do something
             break;
          case R.id.button3:
          // do something
             break;
          default:
          //default
             break;
     }
    }

    } 

   b1.setOnClickListener(ocl);
   b2.setOnClickListener(ocl);
   b3.setOnClickListener(ocl);
```

Or you can do the same for OnTouchListener...just replace the OnClickListener with OnTouchListener...

Comment: Button buttons[] = new Button[49];